# How to store all selected data from listbox in an array in VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, listbox

I would like to know if there is a simple way to store all selected item from a `ListBox` into an array.

I tried to do this with the following code, but it didn't work has excepted. 
`FilterTest()` return me nothing.

```vb
Private Sub ListBox1_Change()

    Dim FilterTest() As Variant
    Dim myMsg As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Count As Integer


    Count = 1

    For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then

            ReDim Preserve FilterTest(Count)
            FilterTest(Count) = ListBox1.List(i)
            Count = Count + 1


        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close. Arrays are base 0 collections (unless specified otherwise) so start counting with 0. You can also drop the parentheses when declaring the variable. Next, redim the variable the first time and then redim preserve it the following iterations.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Change()

    Dim FilterTest As Variant
    Dim myMsg As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Count As Integer

    Count = 0

    For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
            If Count = 0 Then
                Redim FilterTest(Count)
            Else
                Redim Preserve FilterTest(Count)
            End If
            FilterTest(Count) = ListBox1.List(i)
            Count = Count + 1
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: @Dorian what do you mean with "these values"? Please clarify

Comment: Thank you @Tim Stack can you please explain me why with `Count = 1`  this don't work ? ;). I just found the way to do this thats why i deleted the com sorry

Comment: Because `1` is actually the second item of an array. It's a base 0 collection, so `0` is actually the first item

Comment: How can I use the data stored into the array ? When i try to Print all data selected into a message box out of the Sub I got the Error Code 9 : Out of range. For example why does this command line don't work ? `MsgBox FilterTest(1)` I was thinking that this would display the second element of the array..

Comment: It should. That means the array only holds one item. Check the size of the array with `Debug.Print UBound(FilterTest)`

Comment: with this command line I got an error code : 13 "Type incompatible"

Comment: I am afraid I can't help you debug the code without seeing the code. I think that at this point it's best to start a new question as these problems are unrelated to the primary question. It would help to first read about arrays [here](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-array/)

Comment: When I put the mouse on it i got the following message : "The index does not belong to the selection" Does that mean that FilterTest got no element ? There is no more code , i just add 1 Line into an other sub to display a `MsgBox` and i declare the array as a global variable `Private FilterTest() As Variant`

Comment: That's not a global variable, that's a private variable. Plus, remove the parentheses

Comment: sure but Any sub of the module can access it

Comment: Thanks for your link it help me soo much, thanks to it i am able to handle the problem. Thanks for your time and your consideration !

Comment: Absolutely, but a global variable is another level. Did removing the parentheses do the trick?

Comment: No problem, glad I could help you @Dorian